# nftables: How to get BROUTING behavior like ebtables legacy?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nftables

In ebtables, `BROUTING` chain in `broute` table has special behaviors for `ACCEPT` and `DROP` actions: `ACCEPT` means bridging/forward path and `DROP` means routing/input path. For example, to force all non-IPv6 packets to go through NAT, with the proper iptables settings while IPv6 packets are all directly bridged, one could do:

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p ! ipv6 -j DROP -i wan
```

How can I get this behavior in nftables?

Several posts and the old [nftables man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ebtables.8.html#:%7E:text=The%20version%20of%20ebtables%20this%20man%20page%20ships%20with%20does%20not%20support%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20the%20broute%20table.) suggested that this isn't implemented. Also, there're a [thread in the nftables mailing list](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg57662.html) which eventually got no actually valid reply.

Is it still unimplemented? If so, is there any workaround or do I have to use ebtables-legacy? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use brouting in the first place, as opposed to regular routing for everything? We used to have a firewall that did what you're describing (routing for v4 and bridging for v6) and would not do it again, ever. Most likely proxy-NDP would be a functionally cleaner replacement in general. (Such as not messing up IPv6 fragmentation for one...)

Comment: @user1686 You are correct. This is indeed a not very neat solution. However, when I search for routing for v4 and bridging for v6, almost every solution suggests using the BROUTING trick... I'll check out the proxy NDP solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it still unimplemented?

<s>Yes, but still only for a few weeks</s> (Linux kernel 6.4 should be released at end of 2023-06 or start of 2023-07) . The accepted proposition (after a few iterations) for using *broute* with *nftables* in netfilter-devel is from [2023-02-24](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/patch/20230224095251.11249-1-sriram.yagnaraman@est.tech/).

**UPDATE**: it's now officially implemented for `nft` (*nftables*) >= 1.0.8 and even `ebtables-nft` >= 1.8.10, see the update at the end of this answer.

It has been [added in yet-to-be-released **Linux kernel 6.4**](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6e98b09da931a00bf4e0477d0fa52748bf28fcce) on 2023-04-26:

> Netfilter:
>
> - Add nf_tables 'brouting' support, to force a packet to be routed
>   instead of being bridged

and is in the pipeline for the yet-to-be-released next [*nftables* version, probably 1.0.8](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=97672e54518b28923951c96191edb5b7b5f5f294):

> meta: introduce meta broute support
>
> Can be used in bridge prerouting hook to divert a packet to the ip
> stack for routing.
>
> This is a replacement for `ebtables -t broute` functionality.

There's no *ebtables* peculiarity about using accept/drop with a special *broute* type. It's used by setting the *broute* flag in a rule in the *bridge* family type *filter* and *prerouting* hook:

```
meta broute set 1
```

So instead of (using `ebtables-legacy`, since `ebtables-nft` has been lacking support for *broute* until recently):

> ```
> ebtables-legacy -t broute -A BROUTING -p ! ipv6 -j DROP -i wan
> ```

one will do instead something like:

```
table bridge b {
    chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority -250; policy accept;
        ether type != ip6 iifname wan meta broute set 1 accept
    }
}
```

In addition, `ebtables-nft` (shipped through `iptables` sources for the *nftables* backend variant), has also received [an equivalent patch for the yet-to-be-released next version](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/commit/?id=73611d5582e72367a698faf1b5301c836e981465):

> ebtables-nft: add broute table emulation
>
> Use new `meta broute set 1` to emulate `-t broute`.  If `-t broute` is
> given, automatically translate `-j DROP` to `meta broute set 1 accept`
> internally.

which will allow to use `ebtables-nft` instead of `ebtables-legacy` (still with kernel >= 6.4) to accept as-is:

> ```
> ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p ! ipv6 -j DROP -i wan
> ```

---

**UPDATE**

- as written above, kernel [6.4 released around 2023-06-25](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tag/?h=v6.4) received the feature
- as written above, [*nftables* 1.0.8 released around 2023-07-14](https://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter-announce/2023/000251.html) now supports broute:

  > - broute support to short-circuit bridge logic from the bridge
  >   prerouting hook and pass up packets to the local IP stack.
  >
  >   ```
  >   ... meta broute set 1
  >   ```
- [*iptables*: 1.8.10 released around 2023-10-10](https://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter-announce/2023/000254.html) (also providing the binary *ebtables*) now supports broute with `ebtables-nft`:

  > - Broute table support in ebtables-nft

  From this version on, the command below will succeed:

  ```
  ebtables-nft -t broute -A BROUTING -p ! ipv6 -j DROP -i wan
  ```

  As written above `DROP` is actually representing `broute set 1 accept` as displayed back below (displaying is usually ok, altering is usually not ok):

  ```
  # nft list ruleset
  table bridge broute {
    chain BROUTING {
        type filter hook prerouting priority -2147483648; policy accept;
        iifname "wan" ether type != ip6 counter packets 0 bytes 0 meta broute set 1 accept
    }
  }
  ```

  (priority -2147483648  might look weird, but that's the same [hook priority used by `ebtables-legacy`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/bridge/netfilter/ebtable_broute.c?h=v6.4#n86): [`NF_BR_PRI_FIRST`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/netfilter_bridge.h?h=v6.4#n34))